# Window task scheduler... run 3 times a day (4 times on a Friday)

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskscheduler

I have a batch file I want to execute 3 times a day. Monday to Thursday (9am, 12pm, 3pm) but on Friday I want to execute it (9am, 12pm, 3pm, 5pm).

Is there a way to do this with one task in Windows 10? Or will I need a separate task to complete the 5pm run on a Friday?

[image: task scheduler]

Comment: Doesn't this run at 9, 12, 15 but also 18 21 etc.? Anyway it's pretty clear that you will need a special trigger for the Friday 5pm event.

Comment: Yep good point, is there a way to stop it at 15?

Comment: Well, you could put "for a duration of:" 7 or 8 hours. Although it should be tested

Comment: Yeah was just about to reply saying I have found that, thank you.

Comment: If it answers your question, you could consider [accepting my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

More than a separate task, you just need an additional trigger. Add it with New... in the Triggers tab of the Create Task interface.
[image]